# Android proguard and library projects

Tags: android, proguard

the proguard is killing me with messages like that one:

"[proguard] Warning: class [facebook/bin/classes/com/facebook/internal/FileLruCache$StreamHeader.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.facebook.internal.FileLruCache$StreamHeader]"

and the final warning is:

> [proguard] Warning: there were 332 classes in incorrectly named files.
> [proguard]          You should make sure all file names correspond to
> their class names.  [proguard]          The directory hierarchies must
> correspond to the package hierarchies.  [proguard]          If you
> don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,  [proguard]
> you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.

Seems to me I haven't adjusted the library projects that I am using (like facebook) with the proguard.

I don't really want to obfuscate the lib projects, but the lines

> -keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
>
> -keep interface com.facebook.** { *; }

does not to do the trick.

Can you enlighten me on that one?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: class file ... unexpectedly contains class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)

It seems that your configuration contains a -injars option that doesn't point to the root directory of the packages and classes (.../facebook/bin/classes).

However, the standard Android build process already specifies all necessary -injars options for you, so you shouldn't add any.

Comment: Hmm, that is not jar, it comes as library project. How should I specify that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed in with many -dontwarn options in proguard config file.

Also, I don't obfuscate anything that is not in my main package (-keepclass !com.yyy.** { *; } and keepinterface as well). This seems to work nicely.

Comment: Such a setting preserves all classes, fields, and methods in your main packages (with their original names), so you may want to refine it for better shrinking/optimization/obfuscation.

Comment: The idea is to preserve everything outside my main package.

Comment: You're right; I had missed the exclamation mark. It could still be refined, but if it works, it's a good start.

Comment: @Danail - I am also facing same issue. what is  `!com.yyy.** { *; }` could you please tell me little more.